# dropdown con datos repetidos

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, aplicación-web

Hola tengo un `dropdown` que se emplea como filtro y resulta que en las opciones que muestra me pasa todos los datos y por ende se repiten, lo que yo quiero es que si dos datos tienen el mismo nombre que solo aparezca una vez. Como se muestra en la foto solo quiero que aparezca una vez renatta y una vez exequiel. El `filter` se realiza de buena forma, pero necesito agrupar los que se repiten.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el  codigo la primera parte del ts la tengo dentro de una funcion loadData().
HTML

```
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
    <mat-label> <mat-icon>search</mat-icon> Buscar por usuario</mat-label>
    <mat-select matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="person">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let current of persons" [value]="current" (click)="filter()">
            {{current}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS

```
this.currentHistory.forEach((element: any) => {
      if (element.registerBy in this.persons) {
      } else {
        this.persons.push(element.registerBy)
      }
    });

filter() {
    this.currentHistory = this.history.filter((current: any) => current.registerBy === this.person)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se pudo resolver el tema de los registerBy, el codigo quedo asi:

```
this.persons = new Set<string>()
    this.currentHistory.forEach((element: any) => {
      if (element.registerBy in this.persons) {
      } else {
        this.persons.add(element.registerBy)
      }
    });
```

Eso si esto no soluciona si estoy con campos de fecha

Answer (score 0):

Puede probar el ciclo [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) que verificará si hay al menos un elemento, gracias a la función [.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), con la propiedad "registerBy" igual al que se está evaluando. Si no, lo mantendrá en la matriz resultante.

```
filter() {
  this.currentHistory = this.history
    .filter((current: any) => current.registerBy === this.person)
    .reduce((acc: any, curr: any) => {
      if(!acc.some((element) => element.registerBy === curr.registerBy)) {
        acc.push(curr)
      }
      
      return acc
    }, [])
}
```